# I'm trying to make a Matrix from a 2D array but when I print it out its blank?

Tags: java, matrix, multidimensional-array, printing, populate

I'm currently making a program that take a phrase then runs it through 2 matrixs to encrypt it, I'm having trouble with the second matrix where I take a translation of the phrase eg.ADFGESZE and split it up and use the chars to populate the array but the problem the matrix always is blank when I print it and I dont know why as I've looked through my code afew time and cant find the problem and now im confused from pulling chunks of code from Stack Overflow to fix it, Ive posted it in pastebin if any of yous could spot the problem id appreciate it.

Where I get the translation:

```
package polycipher;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Matrix {


    private final char[] CIPHER_KEY = { 'A', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'V', 'X' }; // static morse array
    private final String validChars = "ABCDEFGHIJ

KLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"; // characters which can be used
        public String translation = ""; // for storing it the translation of the phrase

        { // failsafe, our program will be stuck in an infinite loop if
                // number of valid characters is not at lease the square of CIPHER_KEY
                if(validChars.length() < CIPHER_KEY.length*CIPHER_KEY.length) {
                        System.out.println("Error: Not enough valid characters to populate matrix.");
                }

        }

        private char[][] matrix = new char[CIPHER_KEY.length][CIPHER_KEY.length]; // field for holding the generated matrix
        private int[] usedNumbers = new int[validChars.length()]; // field for enforcing unique characters

        { // initiate all array elements to -1 (our "empty" value)
                for (int x = 0; x < usedNumbers.length; x++)
                        usedNumbers[x] = -1;
        }

        public Matrix() { // Matrix default constructor override

                int random;

                for (int i = 0; i < CIPHER_KEY.length; i++) { // for every row

                        for (int j = 0; j < CIPHER_KEY.length; j++) { // for every column

                                validation: while (true) { // do this until I break the loop manually

                                        random = (int) (Math.random() * validChars.length()); // generates a random number from 0 (inclusive) to (36 exclusive)
                                        for (int k = 0; k < usedNumbers.length; k++) { // check every previously used character

                                                if (random == usedNumbers[k]) {
                                                        continue validation; // if this char used before, skip it
                                                } else if (usedNumbers[k] == -1) {

                                                        usedNumbers[k] = random; // if not previously used, store its value as used
                                                        break validation; // and break out of this validation loop
                                                }
                                        }
                                }
                                matrix[i][j] = validChars.split("")[random].charAt(0); // add this character to the matrix
                        }
                }
        }

        public void searchMatrix(){

                Scanner console = new Scanner (System.in);

            String phrase ="";

            System.out.println("\n Enter the message you would like "
                    + "to encrypt with the cipher: ");
            phrase = console.nextLine();

            char[] phraseSplit = phrase.toUpperCase().toCharArray();
            for (int k=0; k<phraseSplit.length; k++) {
                for (int i=0; i<matrix.length; i++) {
                    for (int j=0; j<matrix[i].length; j++) {
                        if (phraseSplit[k] == matrix[i][j]) {
                            System.out.printf("%c has a Array Index %d, %d\n", phraseSplit[k], i, j);
                            if(i == 0){  translation += "A";  }
                            if(i == 1){  translation += "D";  }
                            if(i == 2){  translation += "F";  }
                            if(i == 3){  translation += "G";  }
                            if(i == 4){  translation += "V";  }
                            if(i == 5){  translation += "X";  }
                            if(j == 0){  translation += "A";  }
                            if(j == 1){  translation += "D";  }
                            if(j == 2){  translation += "F";  }
                            if(j == 3){  translation += "G";  }
                            if(j == 4){  translation += "V";  }
                            if(j == 5){  translation += "X";  }

                        }//end if
                    }//end for j
                }//end for i
            }//end for k
            System.out.println("");




} //search end

        public String toString() { // toString override, useful for debugging, prints out the matrix in a 6x6 table
                String output = "  A D F G V X\n";
                for (int i = 0; i < CIPHER_KEY.length; i++) {
                        output += CIPHER_KEY[i] + " ";
                        for (int j = 0; j < CIPHER_KEY.length; j++) {
                                output += matrix[i][j] + " ";
                        }
                        output += "\n";
                }
                return output;
        }


}
```

Where i populate and print the matrix:

```
package polycipher;
import java.util.*;

import polycipher.Matrix;

public class CipherKey {

        Scanner write = new Scanner (System.in);
        Matrix polyCipher = new Matrix();

        private final char[] PHRASE_KEY = { 'J', 'A', 'V', 'A'};
        String[][] matrixStore = new String[PHRASE_KEY.length][PHRASE_KEY.length];

        public void assembleMatrix()  {

                polyCipher.translation = matrixFormatter(polyCipher.translation);
                matrixStore = buildMatrix(polyCipher.translation,"|",",");
                System.out.println(printMatrix(matrixStore));

        }


        public String printMatrix(String s [][]){
            String keyOut = "  J A V A\n";
            for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
           //     keyOut += PHRASE_KEY[i] + " ";
               for (int j = 0; j < s[i].length; j++) {
                    keyOut += s[i][j] + " ";
                }
                keyOut += "\n";
            }
            return keyOut;
        }

        public static String [][] buildMatrix (String translation, String outermarker, String innermarker) {
            // outerdelim may be a group of characters
            String [] sOuter = translation.split ("[" + outermarker + "]");
            int size = sOuter.length;
            // one dimension of the array has to be known on declaration:
            String [][] result = new String [size][];
            int count = 0;
            for (String line : sOuter)
            {
                result [count] = line.split (innermarker);
                ++count;
            }
            return result;
        }

        public String matrixFormatter(String x){

                 String resultstr = "";
                  int i = 0;
                  while(i < x.length()) {
                    // If end of string: only add character.
                    if (i == x.length() - 1) {
                      resultstr += x.substring(i, i + 1);
                    } else {
                      if ( ((i + 1) % 4) == 0) {
                        resultstr += x.substring(i, i + 1)  + "|";
                      } else {
                        resultstr += x.substring(i, i + 1)  + ",";
                      }
                    }
                    i++;
                  }
                  return resultstr;

        }

}


package polycipher;

/* This class will be for inplementing methods in the main and creating a GUI basically */

import polycipher.Matrix;
import polycipher.FileParsing;
import polycipher.CipherKey;
public class ApplicationDriver {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

                //Create and print the matrix
                Matrix polyCipher = new Matrix();
                System.out.print(polyCipher);

                //Search the matrix with our message
                polyCipher.searchMatrix();
                System.out.println("Sting translated: " + polyCipher.translation);
                System.out.println("Corordinates on Cipher: " +
                java.util.Arrays.toString(polyCipher.translation.split("(?<=\\G..)")));

                CipherKey Key = new CipherKey();
                Key.assembleMatrix();

                //Select our file
                FileParsing secretFile = new FileParsing();
                secretFile.openFile();

                //Add the phrase to the file
                secretFile.addPhrase(polyCipher.translation);

                //Close the file
                secretFile.closeFile();



        }

}
```

Output:

```
  A D F G V X
A B Q J 8 E R 
D Z 0 L 6 5 9 
F D 3 Y T I X 
G C 4 O V W A 
V F M N P K S 
X U G H 1 7 2 

 Enter the message you would like to encrypt with the cipher: 
gjhjkjvgjv
G has a Array Index 5, 1
J has a Array Index 0, 2
H has a Array Index 5, 2
J has a Array Index 0, 2
K has a Array Index 4, 4
J has a Array Index 0, 2
V has a Array Index 3, 3
G has a Array Index 5, 1
J has a Array Index 0, 2
V has a Array Index 3, 3

Sting translated: XDAFXFAFVVAFGGXDAFGG
Corordinates on Cipher: [XD, AF, XF, AF, VV, AF, GG, XD, AF, GG]
  J A V A


Enter the .txt file you want to store your phrase in:
```

a matrix should appear below J A V A as the following:

```
J A V A
x x x x
x x x x
x x x x
```

eg.

Comment: you have Math.sqrt() and Math.pow() in Java so instead of doing if(validChars.length() < CIPHER_KEY.length*CIPHER_KEY.length) you could have done 
if(validChars.length() < Math.pow(CIPHER_KEY.length,2))

Comment: What second matrix, where exactly in the code do you encounter the problem? And would you care to explain what this code is supposed to do?

Comment: I'll update it now with the wrong output and the output in going for!